# How to add CSS and JS in Magento2 using Custom Module for all pages?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am trying to add custom CSS and JS file for all the site pages using custom module `Magento_Test` in Magento 2. I have added CSS and JS files in frontend using layout files.

```
Magento/Test/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Magento_Test/css/style.css"/>
        <link src="Magento_Test/js/script.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

CSS and JS files are only included into custom module pages. So, How can I add CSS and JS in Magento2 using Custom Module for all template/sites pages?

Answer (score -1):

According to the [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html) your going to want to use `default_head_blocks.xml` instead of `default.xml`

this works for me if you're using a module and these files have been created -
`Namespace/Module/view/frontend/view/frontend/web/my-styles.css`
`Namespace/Module/view/frontend/view/frontend/web/hello.js`

Now in

`Namespace/Module/view/frontend/view/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="Namespace_Module::my-styles.css" />
    <link src="Namespace_Module::hello.js" />
</head>
```